# How can I have the user hit a key to either speed up or instantly finish the text?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So I'm making a text based adventure for a SENG 100 class.
I'm using this function to type out any text in the game:

```
static void TypeLine(string line)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(line[i]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40); // Sleep for 40 milliseconds
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Is there any way I can have the user hit a key to either speed up or instantly finish the text?

Comment: You can edit the code in your post and change 150 to 40.

Comment: Sure you can. You just have to make Sleep conditional, and handle user click which will change mentioned condition. Do it yourself and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a key has been pressed without reading it:

```
static void TypeLine(string line) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i) {
        Console.Write(line[i]);
        if (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40); // Sleep between characters
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void printText(string textToPrint)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        do
        {
            int x = 0;
            while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
            {
                Console.Write(textToPrint[x]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                x++;
                if (x >= textToPrint.Length)
                    return;
            }
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine("\r" + textToPrint);
        } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.X);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

To call it:

```
printText("I Took an Arrow in the Knee");
```

Comment: Why would you print the partial output again when a key is pressed?

Comment: Well that's a neat way to cheat... though I sense issues if the `textToPrint` is over console width.

Answer (score 0):

Example using threading

```
class Program
{
    static bool running = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Keyboard);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(Print);
        t1.Start();
    }

    static void Print()
    {
        TypeLine("hello world");
    }

    static void TypeLine(string line)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(line[i]);

            if (running)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }

    static void Keyboard()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.LeftShift))
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```